# how to only trim the blanks in the beginning of a string

Tags: java, string, trim

Java method: String.trim() trim blanks (white space, new line, etc.) at both the beginning and end of a string.

How to only trim the blanks in the beginning of a String?

Comment: Note: trim() doesn't trim all white space, it trims `characters < space` which includes quite a few non whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with this:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("^\\s+", "")
```

If you want to remove only specific whitespaces (such as, only blanks), you would replace `\\s` with either the specific character (eg: `"^ +"` for only blanks) or the character class (eg: `"^[ \\t]+"` for blanks and tabs).

**Edit** As per @Pshemo's remark, you can use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`.

Comment: `\\s` contains also line separators `\n` `\r`. Also `replaceFirst` would be enough :)

Comment: @Pshemo I couldn't remember for sure so I added them in. Edited to remove. thx.

Answer (score 1):

try this too

to trim  beginning

```
myString.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

and to trim trailing

```
myString.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the trailing as well. More than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading blank spaces:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("\\s+","");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give your own implementation, then you can use such a method-

```
package com.kvvssut.misc;

public class TrimAtFirst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(trimAtFirst("      \n   \r   \t  You need to trim only before spaces!    "));
    }

    private static String trimAtFirst(String string) {

        int start = 0;
        int len = string.length();

        for (; start < len; start++) {
            char ch = string.charAt(start);
            if (ch != ' ') {
                if (!(ch == '\n' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\r')) {    // include others- I am not sure if more. Also, you can customize based on your needs!
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return string.substring(start, len);
    }

}
```

output- "You need to trim only before spaces!       "